# ViewPager getScrollX return 0 when fragment resumes/recreates

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I am trying to create a Velocity View Pager where in I can scroll through pages like a gallery view. I am experiencing problem while doing scrolling calculations. I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter for ViewPager. For a normal first time run things are cool with getScrollBy returning the actual scroll position taking 1st element at 0. i.e. if I am at 3rd page, getScrollX returns 2400(800px per page) and so on.

Problem arises when I get the fragment that hosts viewpager after a resume from backstack. This time my 3rd page becomes 0 and my first page becomes -2400 position. Some how when android reinflates the adapter it considers current position as 0. I have tried all sorts using setCurrentItem everywhere I could. Some how I feel computeScroll does not work.

It would be great if any one can suggest how can I make the getScrollX return the position considering start as 0 and not the newly inflated current position.

Else I would have no option to create a new fragment everytime I resume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the current position at all times, right?  I'd multiply the current position by the width of your ViewPager, using `ViewPager.getWidth()`.  Since the 2400 is in pixels, you can use the width, in pixels from `getWidth()` to determine the position.

One thing to note is to make sure you use the `getWidth()` value after the view is inflated and measured, otherwise it will return zero for width.

Comment: Thanks.. I wanted to know if there is any way to invalidate the view. But as suggested by you I will play with the scroll Offset as it comes. Thanks

Comment: How to get the "current position" you are referring to?